# Calculation of the integral of the Legendre polynomial of the second kind

Tags: integration, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Please tell me the possible options for calculating the integral of the form $\int\limits_{-\infty}^a\frac{Q_n(x)}{(x+b)^{n+2}}dx$, where $a\in[-2,-\infty)$; $b\in(-a,-\infty)$; $Q_n(x)$ - Legendre polynomial of the second kind.

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: If $|x|>1$, $Q_n(x)$ is complex. Are you expecting a complex number for an answer?